# protobuf-net and sql server ce

Tags: sql-server-ce, protobuf-net

We have been successfully using protobuf-net v1 in a compact framework application to handle serializing our objects for storage in a sql server ce database.

Recently we hit a roadblock apparently due to using too many types (if we don't serialize as many types the error goes away.) Ref: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=50#c6

In desperation (we're supposed to be releasing soon) we downloaded v2 and have been using it (without pre-compiling the serializers). However, we are occassionally getting strange errors when deserializing data -- unknown wire-type 6 and an error reading an int-32 -- somehow it is getting an overflow error when casting to an int which doesn't make sense due to the fact that it was previously serialized using the same method...) It appears to me that we are getting some corruption of the binary data -- but we are simply storing in a varbinary field in sql server ce and pulling it back out.

Does anyone have any ideas how the binary data could be corrupted? (See code below)

FINAL FIX:

Please read Marc's answer for some background. The best I can tell the problem was with how the SetBinary method works -- it does not appear to clear out or truncate existing data -- so if the binary data being saved is smaller than the previous data junk is left at the end.

We fixed it by changing this:

```
if (buffer.Length > 0)
{
    record.SetBytes(insertSet.GetOrdinal(SerializedDataColumnName), 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

to this:

```
if (buffer.Length > 0)
{
    record.SetValue(insertSet.GetOrdinal(SerializedDataColumnName), null);
    record.SetBytes(insertSet.GetOrdinal(SerializedDataColumnName), 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Thank you.

UPDATE: 
Code used to serialize to the DB (code suggestions welcome as well as problem areas):

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
MemoryStream ms = null;
using (SqlCeResultSet insertSet = command.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable))
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        ms = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize<T>(ms, item);
        var record = insertSet.CreateRecord();
        var buffer = ms.GetBuffer();
        if (buffer.Length > 0)
        {
            record.SetBytes(insertSet.GetOrdinal(SerializedDataColumnName), 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            record.SetValue(insertSet.GetOrdinal(SerializedDataColumnName), null);
        }
        insertSet.Update();
    }
}
if (ms != null)
{
    ms.Dispose();
}
```

Code used to deserialize:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (SqlCeResultSet recordSet = command.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable))
    {
        //var serializer = null; //ServiceDepository.TryGetProvider<TypeModel, T>();
        while (recordSet.Read())
        {
            if (!recordSet.IsDBNull(recordSet.GetOrdinal(SerializedDataColumnName)))
            {
                var count = recordSet.GetBytes(recordSet.GetOrdinal(SerializedDataColumnName), 0, null, 0, 1);
                var bytes = new byte[count];
                recordSet.GetBytes(recordSet.GetOrdinal(SerializedDataColumnName), 0, bytes, 0, (int)count);
                if (bytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    var ms2 = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    item = Serializer.Deserialize<T>(ms2);
                }
            }
            if (item == null)
            {
                //handle 'empty' items -- there were no properties
                //  that needed to be serialized
                item = new T();
            }
            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a reproducible example, I will happily investigate (I'm the author).

Comment: @Marc: That's a large part of the problem (and why I am posting here instead of registering a bug at the protobuf-net site). It's random, I have not been able to determine a reproduction scenario, and I'm not sure whether it's a protobuf-net error or an issue with my use of sql server ce's binary storage.

Comment: @Steve can you share any of the serialisation code so I can sanity-check?

Comment: @Marc: code sample added. I have also been trying to use the precompile option in v2 without success, but that's an easier problem to debug so I'm trying to narrow that down. If I gave you a sample of some binary data that wouldn't deserialize (with the object) might that give any indication as to the problem?

Comment: @Steve - no, I think I see it... 2 seconds

Comment: @Steve I am still trying to think how I would get wire-type 6 or an overflow from that, though... Has this code changed at all? Did it used to re-use a memory-stream by any chance? Trailing zeros (which I would expect from the code posted) would cause an error, sure, but it shouldn't be either of those 2. if you *can* send me a sample file, I should at least be able to figure out what state it is in, and how best to proceed...

Comment: (note that re-using a MemoryStream by setting length = position = 0 can leave data in the oversized garbage portion of the buffer, hence why I wonder if this is a possibility; and *just* setting position = 0 without clearing the length would virtually guarantee garbage - but this is all MemoryStream stuff, not specific protobuf-net stuff)

Comment: The code is unchanged except that I removed some lines that set a few other columns but don't interact with the ms or serializer. I'll try to get together a few samples of data that won't deserialize along with their related classes and send it to you. Thank you.

Comment: @Steve - do you still need help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a problem; you are asking the MemoryStream for GetBuffer and using the buffer's length. A likely problem here is that GetBuffer returns the **oversized** backing buffer; you should either call .ToArray() on the MemoryStream to get a correctly sized buffer, or if you don't want to allocate an extra array you can call GetBuffer() but you **must** only store the first memStream.Length bytes from that buffer; the rest should be considered garbage (it is most likely all zeros, but a leading zero is **not valid** in a protobuf field header).

Now, this could just be *part* of the issue, but we should eliminate it first...

Comment: Terrific, I'll try that with much thanks. In v2 things will be faster if I can used the pre-compiled serializer, correct?

Comment: @Steve yes, but *robust* code to package that for CF is still in-progress; at the moment it'll use runtime only (pretty much like v1 does) but hopefully you should find you don't get the annoying MissingMethodException etc. When it *is* fully compiled (as part of build, when that code is fully polished) it should be significantly faster.

Comment: @Steve to summarise: at the moment it should be similar speed to v1 but without the terminal fail; with that speed going up when the packager is ready. I suspect I might need to switch to IKVM for that, but not a biggie.

Comment: See Marc's answer...

@Marc: My apologies - I have been busy chasing an out of memory error and have not worked on this particular issue. In the meantime apparently I cleared out my cookies as Stack Overflow doesn't recognize me anymore and I haven't figured out how to let it know that I am *that* unregistered user... I am not a registered user to hope I don't inconvenience anyone anymore. 

Until I get enough "credits" to comment, I cannot reply. I am still having problems but have not figured out some reproducible binary data that I can send yet that doesn't have large amounts of custome

Comment: 1. Thank you Marc for fixing my SO user woes. 
2. Looks like Marc's estimation that the problem was junk data at the end of the buffer was right. See FIX in the original question.

Comment: @Steve - I'm really glad you got somewhere with this. Any other issues, let me know.